# NumPy array acts differently based on origin (np.max() and np.argmax())

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a function which creates a NumPy array from a data file. I want to then get the maximum value in the array and the index of that value:

```
import numpy as np
def dostuff():
    # open .txt file into lists
    # copy lists into numpy array
    # nested for loops and values copied into numpy array called a

    print a
    print np.max(a)
    print np.argmax(a)
 dostuff()
```

Running this gives:

```
[[  0.64   0.47   0.22   0.1    0.05   0.02]
[  2.19   9.13  10.68   6.44   3.36   1.77]
[  1.84   8.81  12.6    8.31   4.45   2.35]]
2.35
0
```

Clearly something has gone wrong with the np.max() and np.argmax(). This can be shown with the following code

```
def test():
    a = np.array([[0.64, 0.47, 0.22, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02],
                [2.19, 9.13, 10.68, 6.44, 3.36, 1.77],
                [1.84, 8.81, 12.6, 8.31, 4.45, 2.35]])

    print a
    print np.max(a)
    print np.argmax(a)
test()
```

This gives:

```
[[  0.64   0.47   0.22   0.1    0.05   0.02]
[  2.19   9.13  10.68   6.44   3.36   1.77]
[  1.84   8.81  12.6    8.31   4.45   2.35]]
12.6
14
```

...which is what I would have expected. I have no idea why these two (apparently) identical arrays give different results here. Does anyone know what I may have done?

Comment: What is `a.dtype` in both cases?

Comment: You'll have to show more of the code that you currently refer to in the comment `# nested for loops and values...`.

Comment: Obviously, the problem occurs during the 'magic' you describe in the code comments. I'm with @Warren Weckesser: You'll have to show more of the code which actually generates the code...